# What is a Difference between loading a program and executing a program?

Tags: linux, operating-system, execution

For long time I have been thinking that loading a program and executing a program is the same thing in operating systems (linux).But recently I came across some literature where I saw that they distinct between loading a program and executing a program. Are both these things not same. In other words when we click an executable to run it, i assume first some content gets loaded and then executed. But it is still an abstract thing to me. Will be glad if some one lay-down exact detail of what happens exactly and is loading and executing really different things?

Comment: Loading == "setting up the virtual address space and mapping the binary content to it".  Executing == "setting the instruction pointer and letting it go".

Comment: First you load executable code ie. machine instructions in memory and then you execute it, most often by jumping to the address which is the beginning of your executable code.

Comment: Got it. First the program instructions are moved into non-volatile (RAM) memory from hard disk and then are executed. But why do we do that?

Comment: @user3130920: Well, not explicitly.  The pages containing the executable on-disk are *mapped* by the virtual memory system, which then pages them in and out of RAM as necessary.